# Contar saltos de linea en un archivo.txt con Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, archivo, contador

Estoy haciendo un analizador léxico para una clase y una de las cosas que debe de cumplir es contar un los saltos de linea. 
¿Cómo puedo contar los saltos de linea en Python de un archivo de texto? 
Este es mi código, estoy haciendo uso de expresiones regulares?

```
**def newLine(linea):
count = 0
if re.match("\s",linea):
    count += 1
    #print("Salto de linea {0}".format(count))
else:
    pass

print ("Salto de linea totales en el archivo: {0}".format(count))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes contar el número de saltos de línea contando directamente el número de líneas. Aquí te dejo un ejemplo en el que se define un string con 2 saltos de líneas y posteriormente imprime el número de saltos de línea (número de líneas -1):

```
linea = "Hola\nMundo\ncruel"

def newLine(linea):
    resultado=linea.splitlines()
    print(len(resultado)-1)

newLine(linea)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me fue de mucha ayuda